# I am testing the new Opera 11, but it keeps telling me I need to install flash player

Tags: flash

How does one go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opera will grab the plugin from /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so, which is the default location for the flash shared object installed by flashplugin-installer package. So make sure you have both.

If you don't have them, then install the package with:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

If you have flashplugin-installer package and the file mentioned above, but it still doesn't work, then you could try to copy the plugin shared object to ~/.opera/plugins with the following command:

```
cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so ~/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so
```

Also check if you don't have any old version being detected by Opera and disable it. You can do that from opera:plugins page.

For other video types you will need gecko-mediaplayer, which is the only media plugin that works with Opera.

```
sudo apt-get gecko-mediaplayer
```

Comment: BTW, the latest build can be found at http://snapshot.opera.com/unix/awesome_11.00-1094/

Comment: I do not have the said file, what now? and I do have the latest build.

Comment: What do you get from opera:plugins ?

Comment: Added more info to my answer.

Comment: you didn't say anything about making sure I had flashplugin-installer package installed orginally...

Comment: I suppose it worked, since you have accepted the answer. Have fun. I'm also using Opera 11. Is awesome. I had some issues with previous builds, but the latest one is working really nice.

Comment: added info about other video types.

Comment: I think he is going to be ok, I just tested your suggestion and it worked

Comment: Couldn't find ~/.opera. Any other suggestions?