# how to install flash for opera browser? ubuntu 12 04

Tags: 12.04, flash, opera

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix Flash issues?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86164/how-do-i-fix-flash-issues)

[image]

for the opera:plugins setting its had been setup as enable to use the flash player .. and also i do trying to follow the instruction from [I am testing the new Opera 11, but it keeps telling me I need to install flash player](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13767/i-am-testing-the-new-opera-11-but-it-keeps-telling-me-i-need-to-install-flash-p) it still not help me .. what i have after following that link instructions is

```
root@santos:/home/santos# cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so ~/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so
cp: cannot create regular file `/root/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so': No such file or directory
root@santos:/home/santos# sudo apt-get gecko-mediaplayer
E: Invalid operation gecko-mediaplayer
root@santos:/home/santos# cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so ~/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so
cp: cannot create regular file `/root/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so': No such file or directory
```

anyone can help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax in code is wrong.

do this(from normal user, not root! also replace your_username with Your username :) ):

cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /home/your_username/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so

sudo apt-get install gecko-mediaplayer (not sure if it's nessesary but i'm just correcting syntax)

Comment: santos@santos:~$ cp /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so /home/santos/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so
cp: cannot create regular file `/home/santos/.opera/plugins/libflashplayer.so': No such file or directory
santos@santos:~$   

not help yet bro :S

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this, it assumes the file `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so` already exists.

In OPERA select:
**Tools** --> **Preferences** --> **Advanced tab** and then select **Content** from the list on the left.
Find the button named **Plug-in Options...** and click it.

In the Plug-in Options dialog you can add new paths like `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer` and then enable it.  (this info is kept in your $HOME/,opera/pluginpaths.ini file).

Now save the path changes and click the find new plugins.  That should find it for you.  You may need to restart Opera, but that should do it.